# How to write rotation data of all objects to txt-file?

Tags: python, objects, export, transforms

I want to export the rotation of all objects to a .txt file, but I dont know the actual python ommands in Blender. Made some try with google's help:

```
import bpy

ob = bpy.context.object

for ob in bpy.data.objects:

     f=open('output.txt','w')
     f.write(ob.rotation.euler[0])
f.close()
```

Comment: How the output should look like? Have a look into *Templates > Python > Operator File Export*.

Comment: It should be a table with the rotation factor for every object. Thanks for help ;-)

Comment: No problem @Steffen. Text files can not contain tables. Ascii table? What exactly do you mean by "factor"?

Comment: I mean the rotation (for xyz) which defines the mesh object. There are the Location and the Rotation to define every object. And what i need is a export file (maybe txt) where every angle is in. Because i need it for 1000 objects after a rigid body simulation, i dont want to make it by hand (click every object and write down ist from the 3D viewport)

Comment: Ok, I get it. Please add that to your post (edit button below) and ideally also add how the text file should look like at the end @Steffen.

Comment: Thank you very much....with the script you gave as hint it is working